# Custom obfuscated class name in proguard

Tags: android, proguard

Is there any way to set custom class name in proguard (command in proguard.cfg)?

Let's say that I've got class com.scana.MyClass and I want proguard to always obfuscate it as "tx"

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: An update in Google Play went totally wrong.
Old version got this class obfuscated as tx, and the new version obfuscated it as tw, therefore ppl can't log in to my app as it uses serialization to get the data.

Comment: Weird and unexpected. Should you exclude this class from obfuscation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Problem solved.
You can use: `-applymapping file-name` in proguard.cfg

File content example:

`com.scana.MyClass -> tx:`

Comment: Nice, but quit painful to support

Comment: I would be very glad if you define it more, where i can find cfg file

Comment: @MubashirMurtaza this would be a file that you put inside your project and reference to it with `proguardFiles` flag in your build.gradle file.

Comment: now we use .pro file proguard rules, i think cfg was old one.

Comment: Well it doesn't matter in the end what the file extension is - but yes, it used to be cfg